# Load image to GridView from Memory Efficiently

Tags: android, gridview

I am downloading multiple images from internet and storing them on Internal Memory. Now I want to load these images in a GridView, which happens perfectly, but after some time I get `Garbage Collector` message in the log file.
I googled it and what I found was that my application is probably loading more bitmaps into its memory than the application heap size and hence the problem.

**My Adapter:-**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return data.size();
            }

            @Override
            public String getItem(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return data.get(arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arg0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) 
            {
                if(arg1==null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) itemgridsub.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridsubitems, arg2,false);
                }

                TextView user = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.gridsub_tv);

                //setting comics sans as textview's default font
                Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/comic.ttf");
                user.setTypeface(type);
                user.setText(data.get(arg0).substring(3));

                ImageView img =(ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.gridsub_iv);
                //setting the sdim of imageview
                img.getLayoutParams().height=(int) (height/dpi); 
                img.requestLayout();

                Bitmap img1 = loadimage(path+arg0+".jpg");
                //img.setImageBitmap(finalimage);
                img.setImageBitmap(img1);


                return arg1;
            }



        }
```

**Variables Used:-**

- `data` is a **global** `ArrayList<String>` variable.
- `height` is **global** `float`.
- `path` is **global** `String`

**Methods Used:-**

```
public Bitmap loadimage(String path)
    {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }
```

**What My Activity does:-**
Downloads multiple images, stores them to internal memory. Loads them, resize them and replaces with the original images. Now loads them to fit in imageview of GridView.

**What I want:-**
Please tell me if my adapter for loading of gridview is correct. Is it really recycling the view and removing the images when they are out of scope? Or point out any improvement to the code for proper memory management.

**Thanks.**

Comment: Take look here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @Vojtaaa9 Well I am resizing the image and loading the bitmap of the size I want. That's what the link basically tells to do.

Comment: If you have only garbage collector messages and no memory errors or crashes... What is exactly the 'problem'?

Comment: My problem is during these garbage collection message my application is paused and nothing happens in the UI. And the log keep showing the garbage collection message.

Comment: @Mohit how long is your main/UI thread paused?

Comment: Never saw the end of it, stopped the application after 2 minutes of inactivity.